# Description of movable cone

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program

Let $X$ be a normal, $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial projective variety (over $\mathbb{C}$). If we assume that $X$ is a Mori dream space, then by definition its movable cone is rational polyhedral, and  there exist a finite number of small $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial modifications $f_i:X\dashrightarrow X_i$ such that (where $f^\star_0(\text{Nef}(X_0))=\text{Nef}(X)$):
$$\text{Mov}(X)=\bigcup_{i=0}^k f^\star_i(\text{Nef}(X_i)).$$

*Questions.* I would like to understand what, of this properties, fail for a general normal $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial variety (maybe with an extra requirements on  the type of singularities we allow): I am in particular asking this for the closure of the movable cone, since in general it's not closed.

- I guess we don't anymore a finite number of SQM's: nevertheless, can we still say that the movable cone of $X$ is the -infinite- union of the pullbacks of the nef cone of its modifications?
- If not, what do divisors inside the movable cone, but not belonging to the pullback of a nef cone, correspond to?
- Are the pullbacks of the nef cones of its SQM's at least locally rational polyhedral?

Comment: As you probably know, the situation is fairly well understood for adjoint divisors $D\equiv \lambda(K_X+B)$ where $(X,B)$ is klt and $\lambda >0$, see eg Corollary 1.1.5. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0610203.pdf; the case when $K_X\equiv 0$ is particularly interesting because this condition is automatically satisfied by any effective divisor. We then get a locally finite polyhedral decomposition of the interior of the movable cone (see eg. Lemma 2.15 https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.01352.pdf). I don't have any good examples off the top of my head of "bad behaviour" in the non Fano/Calabi-Yau case.